# working with NaN in a dataframe with if condition

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have 2 columns in a dataframe and I am trying to enter into a condition based on if the second one is NaN and First one has some values, unsuccessfully using:

```
if np.isfinite(train_bk['Product_Category_1']) and np.isnan(train_bk['Product_Category_2'])
```

and

```
   if not (train_bk['Product_Category_2']).isnull() and (train_bk['Product_Category_3']).isnull()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use eval:

```
df.eval(' ind =  ((pc1==pc1) & (pc2!=pc2) )*2+((pc1==pc1)&(pc2==pc2))*3')
df.replace({'ind':{0:1})
```